# Is this a recommended use of locks in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, locking

Looking at the following CRUD code, I'd like to know if it is really necessary to use locks and if they can simply be omitted:

```
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns all contacts in the list.
    /// GET /Contacts/ (Content-Type:application/json)
    /// </summary>
    [ActionName("Index"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get), IsAjaxRequest(true)]
    public ActionResult GetAll()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            return new JsonWithStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, Contacts);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the contact with the provided ID.
    /// Get /Contacts/{id}
    /// </summary>
    [ActionName("Item"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetById(Guid id)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            var index = Contacts.FindIndex(x => x.Id == id);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "The provided ID does not exist in the collection");
                return InvalidModelStateFilterAttribute.GetErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ModelState);
            }

            return new JsonWithStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, Contacts[index]);
        }
    }
```

FYI - this is code from a project I am looking at, and wondering if there was a logical reason to use locks in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Look very random to me. Is `Contacts` global object (strange for ASP.Net) or updated from other thread (again no code showing this is the case)?

Comment: Why are you locking at all? Your requests are going to be handled on separate threads and you don't seem to have anything shared. Is `Contacts` a DB context?

Comment: If you Contacts variable is not thread-safe, then those locks would make sure they're not used at the same time by different threads.  Other than that, we'd need more detail to tell "recommended"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locking is not needed for any local variable - if you're creating a new local instance of a type, that variable won't be shared by any other threads unless you specifically pass them around to other threads.

**Edit**: As Michael Gunther pointed out, I missed `Contacts` in the `GetAll()` method - just like with `GetByID()`, if `Contacts` is a static object or if it's somehow passed between threads, it needs locking, otherwise it doesn't.

Your `GetByID()` may need some locking but it's hard to say without knowing all the objects that are used. `Contacts` seems to be a global or a member variable but the need for locking depends if it's static or not or if it's being passed to other threads or not. It's hard to say from your code extract. `Contacts` being a global / static looks very suspicious, though - it's very rare in ASP.NET applications that you need a true global - most global data should be stored in the database or it should be unchanging (in which case you initialize it in a static constructor and then only ever read it afterward, so there's no need to lock).

Comment: `GetAll()` may need locking depending on what it does with `Contacts`, which I'm presuming is a property of `this`.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Yes, you're right. I missed `Contact` in the code. :) I'll update the answer - ty.